# USB-C: USB PD plus Data Transmission: Possible?

Tags: usb, serial, usb-c, usb-pd

### Background

Texas Instruments' reference design [PMP41013](https://www.ti.com/tool/PMP41013) exhibits the use of bidirectional power transmission (DRP) via USB PD via USB-C.

This is principally accomplished through the use of two ICs:

- `BQ25731` — Battery charge controller with USB type-C PD support
- [`TPS25750`](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS25750) — USB Type-C® and USB PD controller

Potential connection cases include:

- Device **receives** power
- Device **provides** power (USB OTG)

### Data Transmission

The USB-C data lines (SSTX±, SSRX±), however, are left floating.

[image: PMP41013 USB-C Connector]

### Issue

I would like to also use the same USB-C port for data transmission.

### Question

Is it possible (and practical) to supplement this design such that:

- Device receives data (ideally with power) for MCU bootloading
- Device receives data (ideally with power) for USB external storage read/write

(For example, could a reference design be provided, portraying the types of additional USB circuitry [not] needed for such an augment?)

Comment: What do you mean under "Device receives data (ideally with power) for USB external storage read/write"? Sounds like you mean that your device acts like USB host to control external USB mass storage?

Comment: @Ale..chenski : I would like for a single USB C port to offer the possibility to either : draw USB PD 20 [V] 3 [A] or less to charge its battery, or offer USB PD 20 [V] 3 [A] or less from its battery to a single device (such as a mobile device), or alternatively interface with a PC USB C port for programming MCU or storage - ideally while simultaneously drawing any available power from the PC port (with the understanding that the PC port might not specifically be USB PD, but ideally would offer something better than 5 [V] 0.5 [A] because it is USB C which could potentially offer 1.5 or 3 [A]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible …

Yes, that's possible. It's part of what USB-C and USB PD was designed for.

[image: Slide: USB Display Docking Example]
 <sup>From the USB Implementers Forum 2012 presentation "USB Power Delivery – 1.0 Introduction". [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20130123140132if_/http://www.usb.org:80/developers/powerdelivery/PD_1.0_Introduction.pdf) via archive.org</sup>

> (and practical)

It's also how basically all modern laptop docks function – you plug in *one* USB-C connector and get access to a USB hub, DisplayPort alternative modes and USB PD to charge the laptop while doing all this.

> to supplement *this* design such that

(emphasis mine)

Yes! That's why USB-PD uses only the CC and VBUS lines; to stay orthogonal to what else is happening on the connector.

Comment: That's great! Could you further specify a reference design which includes an example of the data side of transmission (or some reference to the types of ICs needed for the data side of transmission)? Do I need a separate controller? A redriver? Other? All of the above? (etc.)

Comment: can't, that's a bit of a more complex question and depends on what you actually want to do over that data line. I understand the TPS 25750 comes with a web-based firmware design tool, which you can feed with the configuration you need. So play with that. Ask a new question when you hit a roadblock.