# USB D± : Simultaneous BC 1.2 and USB2.0 data transmission Possible?

Tags: usb, usb-pd, usb-2

### Background

USB pins D± are used for:

- USB 2.0 data transmission
- Battery charging (BC 1.2)

### Question

Can D± be used for USB 2.0 data transmission **and** BC 1.2, or does BC 1.2 preclude the use of USB 2.0 data transmission?

### Added background

Continued from this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/687547/usb-c-adding-data-transmission-to-usb-pd).

Comment: That other question is about USB power delivery, but you're asking about the (mostly obsolete) Battery Charging spec. Is that right? You want BC and not PD?

Comment: @user1850479 : The reference design (which is recent) calls for sending D± to the IC. The IC states that this is for BC 1.2 compatibility. In my specific case, I want to use USB PD to dual role power (to charge a battery and alternatively to use that battery to charge other devices). I also want to use the same USB C port to connect to a PC to interface with the MCU. In such a case, the PC would be the host — and I would gladly accept any power from the PC port as well.

Comment: BC (ab-)uses the data lines for the signaling - this prevents data mode altogether. USB PD is something entirely different. You can make a device than can use both modes - like old smart phones did. These don't charge the battery fast when connected to a PC.

Comment: @TurboJ : Thank you. Is it yet common for PC USB ports to provide power via USB PD? When I am data interfacing with my device, I would love for the host PC USB port to also provide sufficient power to interface with my device even with a battery pack removed. If the host PC USB port cannot be expected to provide USB PD power, what is the best I can expect? Standard 5 [V] 0.5 [A]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB Power Delivery essentially replaced USB Battery Charging, so while your controller supports both standards (presumably for backwards compatibility with legacy products), if you want USB-PD and don't have old hardware that needs USB-BC, you can safely ignore the USB-BC parts. You should probably do this since BC is ancient at this point.

As for your other question:

> Is it yet common for PC USB ports to provide power via USB PD?

Not at all common, so you should assume only 500mA if you're using USB 2.0. If you need more than that, you can get 900mA by using USB 3.0. Beyond that you will typically need a dedicated AC adapter or (less commonly) a USB-PD hub.

Comment: My laptop (a Dell Inspiron 2-in-1) actually does have a bidirectional USB-C PD port.

Comment: [Thunderbolt 3/4](https://www.thunderbolttechnology.net/tech/faq) certification requires that a computer provide 15 W (i.e. 5 V 3 A) power supply on its so-labeled ports.

Comment: @user71659 Ports can provide significantly higher than 500 mA (in fact most do in practice), but you have to negotiate that (e.g. with PD) and deal with the possibility that the device says no. You can't (or at least should not) make a device that assumes all ports it plugs into will provide 3A.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible! Using BC 1.2 doesn't preclude data transfer, as long as your downstream-facing port is able to combine the two - I've seen laptop-intended USB port controllers from TI that support both, adding this feature to a typical USB 2.0 port. [This video](https://www.ti.com/video/6258839979001) from Texas Instruments explains in-detail how a BC advertisement and USB 2.0 data transfer can be combined inside a single pair at the same time, using a BC 1.2 mode called CDP (Charging Downstream Port). For more detail, you can refer to [the Battery Charging v1.2 specification,](https://www.usb.org/document-library/battery-charging-v12-spec-and-adopters-agreement) which is openly available on usb.org.

This is a general answer, however - you don't seem to need that in your application, so I will go and provide an answer there too.